# Subsequent scenes in ScrollMagic are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll, scrollmagic

I use ScrollMagic on my website. It is a one-page web site with 7 "sections". First one animates fine I'm struggling with animating multiple scenes. I need every section to be animated when user is scrolling. First one is okay, but the second after adding scene is just blank.

(part of) **HTML**:

```
<section id="slide1" ........>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
      <img id="racket" src="svg/racket.svg">
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
      <img id="racket2" src="svg/racket2.svg">
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
      <img id="racket3" src="svg/racket3.svg">
    </div>
</section>

<section id="slide2" .....>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
      <img id="earth" src="svg/earth.svg">
    </div>
</section>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {

var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

var slide1_moves = new TimelineMax()
    .to("#racket", 10, {x:500, y:-300, opacity: 0}, 0.2)
    .to("#racket2", 10, {x:-500, y:-400, opacity: 0}, 2)
    .to("#racket3", 10, {x:-200, y: -300, opacity:0}, 0.5)


var scene1 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        duration: 3000,    
        offset: 0        
    })
    scene1.setTween(slide1_moves)
    scene1.setPin("#slide1") 
    scene1.addTo(controller)  

var slide2_moves= new TimelineMax()
    .to("#earth", 10, {x:500, y:-300, opacity: 0}, 0.2)

// create a scene with custom options and assign a handler to it.
var scene2 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        duration: 5000,
        offset: 0
});
scene2.setTween(pohyby_slide2)
scene2.setPin("#slide2") 
scene2.addTo(controller)

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, but I do use a different syntax on a page of mine (which is working).

Your code is:

```
var scene2 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        duration: 5000,
        offset: 0
});
scene2.setTween(pohyby_slide2)
scene2.setPin("#slide2") 
scene2.addTo(controller)

});
```

I would write that differently (note the multiple omission of "scene2" and the different handling of semicolons and parenthesis:

```
var scene2 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        duration: 5000,
        offset: 0
})
.setTween(pohyby_slide2)
.setPin("#slide2") 
.addTo(controller);
```